# xslt to append (add suffix) to all ids and idref present in input xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to append or concat a random number i.e. 6869 to too many ids and idref present in my request.

The actual request consists of thousands of lines and there are many ids in it.

Sample Request :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <jsonObject>
            <_JsonReader_PS_id>1</_JsonReader_PS_id>
            <Children>              
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>1</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>4</_JsonReader_PS_id>

                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>5</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
                    <Instance>
                        <_JsonReader_PS_id>6</_JsonReader_PS_id>                        
                        <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                        <Children>
                            <_JsonReader_PS_id>7</_JsonReader_PS_id>                            
                            <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>8</_JsonReader_PS_id>                                
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>7</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>10</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>7</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>12</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>7</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                                </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>14</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>7</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>16</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>7</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Parent>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_ref>6</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                            </Parent>
                        </Children>
                        <Parent>
                            <_JsonReader_PS_ref>5</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                        </Parent>
                        </Instance>
                    <Guid>b5c75f37-6381-45f8-806b-c22a49ab6962</Guid>
                    <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                    <Parent>
                        <_JsonReader_PS_ref>4</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                    </Parent>
                    </Children>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>1</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>19</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>1</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent></Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>21</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>1</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
                </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>23</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>1</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
        </jsonObject>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Desired Output :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <jsonObject>
            <_JsonReader_PS_id>16869</_JsonReader_PS_id>
            <Children>              
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>16869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>46869</_JsonReader_PS_id>

                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Children>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_id>56869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                    
                    <Instance>
                        <_JsonReader_PS_id>66869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                        
                        <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                        <Children>
                            <_JsonReader_PS_id>76869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                            
                            <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>86869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                                
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>76869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>106869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>76869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>126869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>76869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                                </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>146869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>76869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Children>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_id>166869</_JsonReader_PS_id>                               
                                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                                <Parent>
                                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>76869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                                </Parent>
                            </Children>
                            <Parent>
                                <_JsonReader_PS_ref>66869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                            </Parent>
                        </Children>
                        <Parent>
                            <_JsonReader_PS_ref>56869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                        </Parent>
                        </Instance>
                    <Guid>b5c75f37-6381-45f8-806b-c22a49ab6962</Guid>
                    <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                    <Parent>
                        <_JsonReader_PS_ref>46869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                    </Parent>
                    </Children>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>16869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>196869</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>16869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent></Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>216869</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>16869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
                </Children>
            <Children>
                <_JsonReader_PS_id>236869</_JsonReader_PS_id>               
                <?xml-multiple  Children?>
                <Parent>
                    <_JsonReader_PS_ref>16869</_JsonReader_PS_ref>
                </Parent>
            </Children>
        </jsonObject>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

xslt I tried but is failing to produce desired output. It is not able to access the value of xpath field

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="id" match="ID" use="." />

            <!-- identity transform -->
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="//_JsonReader_PS_id">
                <xsl:copy>        
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//_JsonReader_PS_id, '6869')"/> 
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="_JsonReader_PS_ref">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//_JsonReader_PS_ref, '6869')"/>         
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In output the number is getting appended but the original value of the field is changed to 1 always. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:template match="//_JsonReader_PS_id">
   <xsl:copy>        
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(//_JsonReader_PS_id, '6869')"/> 
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Do this...

```
<xsl:template match="_JsonReader_PS_id">
    <xsl:copy>        
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '6869')"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Where `.` represents the current node you have just matched. (Doing `//_JsonReader_PS_id` gets all `_JsonReader_PS_id` in the document, not just the one you are matched. And when you put that in a `concat` statement, it will just use the first one in the document).

And similarly for the other template

```
<xsl:template match="_JsonReader_PS_ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '6869')"/>         
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, these two templates can be combined into one

```
<xsl:template match="_JsonReader_PS_id|_JsonReader_PS_ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '6869')"/>         
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5d